# How to split CSV columns?

Tags: python, csv

i am using the following code to export dictionary/json data to CSV, I am trying to split the "process_hash" column into two columns, so that there's one for MD5 and another column for SHA256, along with the other existing columns.

The "process_hash" column currently contains list values, i am not sure how to split them into columns, MD5 and SHA256?

```
[{'device_name': 'fk6sdc2',
  'device_timestamp': '2020-10-27T00:50:46.176Z',
  'event_id': '9b1bvf6e17ee11eb81b',
  'process_effective_reputation': 'LIST',
  'process_hash': ['bfc7dcf5935830f3a9df8e9b6425c37a',
                   'ca9f3a24506cc518fc939a33c100b2d557f96e040f712f6dd4641ad1734e2f19'],
  'process_name': 'c:\\program files '
                  '(x86)\\toh122soft\\thcasdf3\\toho34rce.exe',
  'process_username': ['JOHN\\user1']},
 {'device_name': 'fk6sdc2',
  'device_timestamp': '2020-10-27T00:50:46.176Z',
  'event_id': '9b151f6e17ee11eb81b',
  'process_effective_reputation': 'LIST',
  'process_hash': ['bfc7dcf5935f3a9df8e9b6830425c37a',
                   'ca9f3a24506cc518fc939a33c100b2d557f96e040f712f6dd4641ad1734e2f19'],
  'process_name': 'c:\\program files (x86)\\oft\\tf3\\tootsice.exe',
  'process_username': ['JOHN\\user2']},
 {'device_name': '6asdsdc2',
  'device_timestamp': '2020-10-27T00:50:46.176Z',
  'event_id': '9b151f698e11eb81b',
  'process_effective_reputation': 'LIST',
  'process_hash': ['9df8ebfc7dcf5935830f3a9b6425c37a',
                   'ca9f3a24506cc518ff6ddc939a33c100b2d557f96e040f7124641ad1734e2f19'],
  'process_name': 'c:\\program files (x86)\\toht\\th3\\tohce.exe',
  'process_username': ['JOHN\\user3']}]
```

Code to export to csv:

```
def toCSV(res):
    with open('EnrichedEvents.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ['process_hash', 'process_name', "process_effective_reputation"]
        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, extrasaction='ignore')
        dict_writer.writeheader()

        entries = set()
        for data in res:
            val = tuple(','.join(v) if isinstance(v, list) else v for v in data.values())
            if val not in entries:
                dict_writer.writerow(data)
                entries.add(val)
```

csv data:

```
 process_hash    process_name    process_effective_reputation
 ['f810a809e9cdf70c3189008e07c83619', '58d44528b60d36b515359fe234c9332ccef6937f5c950472230ce15dca8812e2']    c:\windows\system32\delltpad\apmsgfwd.exe   ADAPTIVE_WHITE_LIST
 ['73ca11f2acf1adb7802c2914e1026db899a3c851cd9500378c0045e0']    c:\users\zdr3dds01\documents\sap\sap gui\export.mhtml   NOT_LISTED
 ['f810a809e9cdf70c3189008e07c83619', '58d44528b60d36b515359fe234c9332ccef6937f5c950472230ce15dca8812e2']    c:\windows\system32\delltpad\apmsgfwd.exe   ADAPTIVE_WHITE_LIST
 ['f810a809e9cdf70c3189008e07c83619', '58d44528b60d36b515359fe234c9332ccef6937f5c950472230ce15dca8812e2']    c:\windows\system32\delltpad\apmsgfwd.exe   ADAPTIVE_WHITE_LIST
 ['582f018bc7a732d63f624d6f92b3d143', '66505bcb9975d61af14dd09cddd9ac0d11a3e2b5ae41845c65117e7e2b046d37']    c:\users\jij09\appdata\local\kingsoft\power word 2016\2016.3.3.0368\powerword.exe   ADAPTIVE_WHITE_LIST
```

What I'm trying to achieve with the CSV file:

```
 md5   sha256   process_name  process_effective_reputation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by processing the `process_hash` field list separately and just copying the other two fields as shown below:

```
import csv

data = [{'device_name': 'fk6sdc2',
          rest of your data ...

def toCSV(res):
    with open('EnrichedEvents.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = 'md5,sha256,process_name,process_effective_reputation'.split(',')

        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, extrasaction='ignore')
        dict_writer.writeheader()

        for obj in res:
            md5, sha256 = obj['process_hash']  # Extract values from process_hash list.
            row = {'md5': md5, 'sha256': sha256}  # Initialize a row with them.
            row.update({field: obj[field]  # Copy the last two fields into it.
                            for field in fieldnames[-2:]})
            dict_writer.writerow(row)

toCSV(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way.  The function `apply()` converts one list to multiple columns.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'device_name': 'fk6sdc2',
  'device_timestamp': '2020-10-27T00:50:46.176Z',
  'event_id': '9b1bvf6e17ee11eb81b',
  'process_effective_reputation': 'LIST',
  'process_hash': ['bfc7dcf5935830f3a9df8e9b6425c37a',
                   'ca9f3a24506cc518fc939a33c100b2d557f96e040f712f6dd4641ad1734e2f19'],
  'process_name': 'c:\\program files '
                  '(x86)\\toh122soft\\thcasdf3\\toho34rce.exe',
  'process_username': ['JOHN\\user1']},
 {'device_name': 'fk6sdc2',
  'device_timestamp': '2020-10-27T00:50:46.176Z',
  'event_id': '9b151f6e17ee11eb81b',
  'process_effective_reputation': 'LIST',
  'process_hash': ['bfc7dcf5935f3a9df8e9b6830425c37a',
                   'ca9f3a24506cc518fc939a33c100b2d557f96e040f712f6dd4641ad1734e2f19'],
  'process_name': 'c:\\program files (x86)\\oft\\tf3\\tootsice.exe',
  'process_username': ['JOHN\\user2']},
 {'device_name': '6asdsdc2',
  'device_timestamp': '2020-10-27T00:50:46.176Z',
  'event_id': '9b151f698e11eb81b',
  'process_effective_reputation': 'LIST',
  'process_hash': ['9df8ebfc7dcf5935830f3a9b6425c37a',
                   'ca9f3a24506cc518ff6ddc939a33c100b2d557f96e040f7124641ad1734e2f19'],
  'process_name': 'c:\\program files (x86)\\toht\\th3\\tohce.exe',
  'process_username': ['JOHN\\user3']}]
```

Now process the data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['process_hash', 'process_name', 'process_effective_reputation'])
df[['md5', 'sha256']] = df['process_hash'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x))
df = df.drop(columns='process_hash')
```

Finally here are the results:

```
print(df)

                                        process_name  \
0  c:\program files (x86)\toh122soft\thcasdf3\toh...   
1        c:\program files (x86)\oft\tf3\tootsice.exe   
2          c:\program files (x86)\toht\th3\tohce.exe   

  process_effective_reputation                               md5  \
0                         LIST  bfc7dcf5935830f3a9df8e9b6425c37a   
1                         LIST  bfc7dcf5935f3a9df8e9b6830425c37a   
2                         LIST  9df8ebfc7dcf5935830f3a9b6425c37a   

                                              sha256  
0  ca9f3a24506cc518fc939a33c100b2d557f96e040f712f...  
1  ca9f3a24506cc518fc939a33c100b2d557f96e040f712f...  
2  ca9f3a24506cc518ff6ddc939a33c100b2d557f96e040f...
```